# Deleting a file with Jersey client gives "server redirected too many times" error

Tags: rest, jersey

I have a bunch of automation test cases implemented with Apache Jersey client. Everything works very well except for one case when I delete a file against the RESTful webservice. The error happens for some time, and it can't be reproduced everytime, but it does happen.

The code I have for deleting the file is quite simple and intuitive with Jersey

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource resource = client.resource(uri);
ClientResponse response = resource.delete(ClientResponse.class);
```

The above codes are deleting a file on the server specified by the uri AND that's the only case where I got 'server redirected too many times (20)' error. It passes sometime, but it does fail sometime. I'm looking for more clues to start with the investigation.

The exceptions I got are:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.delete(WebResource.java:272)
<more my user exceptions are skipped here...>

Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1446)
java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:240) com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.delete(WebResource.java:272)
```

Hope somebody can give some hints?
Thanks.

Comment: How does your resource look like? Can you paste the delete method on the server side?

Comment: Martin, I don't have the method on server side. The API has been working well for a while without problems. DELETE action also works if the request is sent from web page XmlHttpRequest. It's only Jersey client that I found out there is a problem with. It also works with deleting the json object on server, but randomly got the above too many redirection errors when deleting an image file on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the server is sending repeated redirects for some reason.

Call `client.setFollowRedirects(false);` on your Jersey client instance to avoid the client getting into a redirect loop.